# Executing command remotely | Keep only 5 recent files/directories

Tags: bash, powershell, unix, ssh

I created a test directory on a remote server. To simulate this command, I created 6 files inside this test directory. The expected behavior of the command is to only keep 5 recent files in the directory. Good news is this command works!

My only trouble is I cannot execute the same command remotely. Only difference is the "" notation for the remote execution:

```
ssh account@someremoteserver.com "rm -rf `ls -t /usr/local/testingCommands | awk 'NR>5'`"
```

The reason for this is.. I have a Jenkins CI server that needs to remotely clean up the remote server, only keeping 5 most recent files.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Due to your use of double quotes, you are executing the `ls` and `awk` locally. You have to use single quotes to ensure that the backquotes are passed to the remote side.

Comment: how about `'rm -rf $(ls -t ... | awk "NR>5")'`

Comment: This isn't a powershell issue...
Could you please remove that tag?

Comment: Can you create a service on the remote server instead of passing the command via ssh?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
ssh account@someremoteserver.com '/usr/bin/ls -1Qt /usr/local/testingCommands | awk "NR > 5" | /usr/bin/xargs /usr/bin/rm -rf'
```

Remarks:

- Use absolute directory for all commands (security reasons)
- `rm ... $(...)` really too dangerous, so invert `rm` and `ls` commands:

  - use `ls` command with one file per line option (`-1`), quoted filenames (`-Q`) for filenames with spaces